# How to send Camera Stream from Unity to the web browser?

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine, webrtc, augmented-reality

I am trying to connect a unity client to a browser client using Webrtc. This step is complete the two clients are now connected (Signaling is complete). What I need to do next is to send the video stream from the c# **Camera** object to the other peer (browser). Here's what have done which is not working and I do not know why?

The c# code :

```
var track = arCamera.CaptureStreamTrack(1280, 720, 3000);
localConnection.AddTrack(track);
```

Then I register the ontrack event for the RTCPeerConnection Object
The javascript code:

```
 function handleTrack (e) {
    console.log("Recieved a Track");
    remotePeerVideo.current.srcObject = e.streams[0];
}
```

When I
console.log(e.streams); this is the result:

```
[MediaStream]

0:{active: true, id: "9322aaa7-69b6-4ef4-8f49-c457ef4ffd16"}
```

I add this track to the srcObj of a video element, but it does not work. Any Ideas what might be wrong or if there is another way to get the video stream from the c# Camera Object?